# Tracking online user with GraphQL Apollo

Tags: node.js, websocket, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I need to handle events "user is now online" and "user is now offline" on GraphQL Apollo Node.js server. What's the best way to do it?

**My investigation**: I pretty sure that I don't need to implement any heartbeat logic, because subscriptions are working on WebSockets. But I didn't find any info in their docs how to handle WebSockets events like "connecting" and "disconnecting" from the subscription... Actually I can handle those events from the outside of actual subscription:

```
SubscriptionServer.create({
    execute,
    subscribe,
    schema,
    onConnect = (...args) => {
        console.log('User connected')
    },
    onDisconnect = (...args) => {
        console.log('User disconnected')
    }
}, {
    server: ws,
    path: '/subscriptions'
})
```

But can't determine which user is connected via this socket.

**My implementation**: for now I made it work like that:

1. We have express middleware for all the calls, it is pushing user object from jsonwebtoken to `req` object. Here I can trigger "user is now online" logic.
2. I've created separate subscription, client subscribes on it on login and unsubscribes on logout. Since there is no *unsubscribe* handler, I manage to determine that filter function gets called on user disconnect without payload, so I did this approach:

   ```
   userOnlineSubscription: {
       subscribe: withFilter(
           () => pubSub.asyncIterator('userOnlineSubscription'),
               async (payload, variables) => {
                   if (!payload) {
                       // set user offline
               }
               return false
           }
       )
   }
   ```

As for me, the solution above is ugly. Can someone recommend the better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this approach

```
onConnect (connectionParams, webSocket) {
  const userPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (connectionParams.jwt) {
      jsonwebtoken.verify(
        connectionParams.jwt,
        JWT_SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(new Error('Invalid Token'))
          }

          resolve(
            User.findOne({
              where: { id: decoded.id }
            })
          )
        }
      )
    } else {
      reject(new Error('No Token'))
    }
  })

  return userPromise.then(user => {
    if (user) {
      return { user: Promise.resolve(user) }
    }

    return Promise.reject(new Error('No User'))
  })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this approach "jsonwebtoken.verify" will be called twice: in this handler and inside the graphQL subscriptions. But I couldn't find better solution, so it must be the accepted answer since it works fine.